# email template variable automatically becomes anchor link?

Tags: javascript, nodemailer

I'm doing an extremely simple contact form where I'm capturing the form data and sending it to an email. My question is, when I capture the `req.body.email` variable in my form and send it out to email, it's automatically creating a `<a></a>` tag which I did not create. I tried to get rid of the blue color on the email variable by setting `text-decoration:none;` and `color:#fff !important;` but the email variable that I send to my email is still blue and since the anchor tag is being generated dynamically I cannot do any inline styles in my template? Is there a way to change the blue color on the dynamically created email?

Here is my code:

**Model:**

```js
var contactMail = require('./Contactmail');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var inlineCss = require('nodemailer-juice');

var contact = {
    contactsendEmail: function (data, callback) {
        var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'gmail',
            auth: {
                user:'...',
                pass:'...'
            },
            tls: {
                rejectUnauthorized: false
            }
        });
        var mailOptions = {
            from: 'test@test.com',
            to: 'johnsmith@test.com',
            subject: 'Form Submission Results',
            html: contactMail.contactTemplate(data)
        };
        transporter.use('compile',inlineCss(mailOptions));
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, callback, function(error, info){
            if(error){
                return console.log(error);
            } else {
                return console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
            }
        });
    }
}

module.exports = contact;
```

**Email Template:**

```js
var contactMail = {
    contactTemplate: function(data){
        var getYear = new Date().getFullYear('yyyy');

        var message = '';
            message += "<!doctype html>"
            message += "<html>"
            message += "<head>"
            message += "<title>"
            message += "Form Submission Results"
            message += "</title>"
            message += "<!--[if !mso]><!-- -->"
            message += "<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>"
            message += "<!--<![endif]-->"
            message += "<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>"
            message += "<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>"
            message += "<style type='text/css'>"
            message += "#outlook a {padding: 0;}"
            message += ".ReadMsgBody {width: 100%;}"
            message += ".ExternalClass {width: 100%;}"
            message += ".ExternalClass * {line-height: 100%;}"
            message += "body {margin: 0;padding: 0;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;}"
            message += "table,td {border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;}"
            message += "img {border: 0;height: auto;line-height: 100%;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;}"
            message += "p {display: block;margin: 13px 0;}"
            message += "</style>"
            message += "<!--[if !mso]><!-->"
            message += "<style type='text/css'>"
            message += "@media only screen and (max-width:480px) {@-ms-viewport {width: 320px;}@viewport {width: 320px;}}"
            message += "</style>"
            message += "<style type='text/css'>@media only screen and (min-width:480px) {.mj-column-per-100 {width: 100% !important;}}"
            message += "</style>"
            message += "</head>"
            message += "<body style='background-color:#F4F4F4;'>"
            message += "<div style='background-color:#F4F4F4;'>"
            message += "<!--[if mso | IE]>"
            message += "<table align='center' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='width:600px;' width='600'>"
            message += "<tr>"
            message += "<td style='line-height:0px;font-size:0px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;'>"
            message += "<![endif]-->"
            message += "<div style='background:#000000;background-color:#000000;Margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;'>"
            message += "<table align='center' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' role='presentation' style='background:#000000;background-color:#000000;width:100%;'>"
            message += "<tbody>"
            message += "<tr>"
            message += "<td style='direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:20px 0;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;'>"
            message += "<!--[if mso | IE]>"
            message += "<table role='presentation' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>"
            message += "<tr>"
            message += "<td style='vertical-align:top;width:600px;'>"
            message += "<![endif]-->"
            message += "<div class='mj-column-per-100 outlook-group-fix' style='font-size:13px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top; 'width:100%;'>"
            message += "<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' role='presentation' style='vertical-align:top;' width='100%'>"
            message += "<tr>"
            message += "<td align='center' style='font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;word-break:break-word;'>"
            message += "<table align='center' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' role='presentation' style='border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;'>"
            message += "<tbody>"
            message += "<tr>"
            message += "<td style='width:180px;'>"
            message += "<img height='auto' src='http://5vph.mj.am/img/5vph/b/1g86w/0g67t.png' style='border:none;display:block;outline:none;text-decoration:none;width:100px;'/>"
            message += "</td>"
            message += "</tr>"
            message += "</tbody>"
            message += "</table>"
            message += "</td>"
            message += "</tr>"
            message += "</table>"
            message += "</div>"
            message += "<!--[if mso | IE]>"
            message += "</td>"
            message += "</tr>"
            message += "</table>"
            message += "<![endif]-->"
            message += "</td>"
            message += "</tr>"
            message += "</tbody>"
            message += "</table>"
            message += "</div>"
            message += "<!--[if mso | IE]>"
            message += "</td>"
            message += "</tr>"
            message += "</table>"
            message += "<table align='center' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='width:600px;' width='600'>"
            message += "<tr>"
            message += "<td style='line-height:0px;font-size:0px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;'>"
            message += "<![endif]-->"
            message += "<div style='background:#000000;background-color:#000000;Margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;'>"
            message += "<table align='center' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' role='presentation' style='background:#000000;background-color:#000000;width:100%;'>"
            message += "<tbody>"
            message += "<tr>"
            message += "<td style='direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:0 0 0 0;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;'>"
            message += "<!--[if mso | IE]>"
            message += "<table role='presentation' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>"
            message += "<tr>"
            message += "<td style='vertical-align:top;width:600px;'>"
            message += "<![endif]-->"
            message += "<div class='mj-column-per-100 outlook-group-fix' style='font-size:13px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;width:100%;vertical-align:top;'>"
            message += "<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' role='presentation' style='vertical-align:top;width:100%;'>"
            message += "<tr>"
            message += "<td align='left' style='font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;padding-top:25px;padding-bottom:5px;word-break:break-word;'>"
            message += "<div style='font-size:13px;line-height:22px;text-align:left;color:#55575d;'>"
            message += "<p style='line-height: 60px; text-align: center; margin: 10px 0;font-size:35px;color:#fcfcfc;'><b>Form Submission Results</b></p>"
            message += "</div>"
            message += "</td>"
            message += "</tr>"
            message += "<tr>"
            message += "<td align='left' style='font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;word-break:break-word;'>"
            message += "<div style='font-size:13px;line-height:1;text-align:left;color:#000000;'>"
            message += "<p style='color: #fff; font-size:16px;'>Fullname: <span style='color:#ccc;'>"+data.fullName+"</span></p>"
            message += "<p style='color: #fff; font-size:16px;'>Email: <span style='color:#ccc;'>"+data.email+"</span></p>"
            message += "<p style='color: #fff; font-size:16px;'>Subject: <span style='color:#ccc;'>"+data.subject+"</span></p>"
            message += "<p style='color: #fff; font-size:16px;'>Message: <span style='color:#ccc;line-height:24px;'>"+data.message+"</span></p>"
            message += "</div>"
            message += "</td>"
            message += "</tr>"
            message += "</table>"
            message += "</div>"
            message += "<!--[if mso | IE]>"
            message += "</td>"
            message += "</tr>"
            message += "</table>"
            message += "<![endif]-->"
            message += "</td>"
            message += "</tr>"
            message += "</tbody>"
            message += "</table>"
            message += "</div>"
            message += "<!--[if mso | IE]>"
            message += "</td>"
            message += "</tr>"
            message += "</table>"
            message += "<table align='center' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='width:600px;' width='600'>"
            message += "<tr>"
            message += "<td style='line-height:0px;font-size:0px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;'>"
            message += "<![endif]-->"
            message += "<div style='background:#000000;background-color:#000000;Margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;'>"
            message += "<table align='center' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' role='presentation' style='background:#000000;background-color:#000000;width:100%;'>"
            message += "<tbody>"
            message += "<tr>"
            message += "<td style='direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:20px 0;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;'>"
            message += "<!--[if mso | IE]>"
            message += "<table role='presentation' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>"
            message += "<tr>"
            message += "<td style='vertical-align:top;width:600px;'>"
            message += "<![endif]-->"
            message += "<div class='mj-column-per-100 outlook-group-fix' style='font-size:13px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top; width:100%;'>"
            message += "<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' role='presentation' style='vertical-align:top;' width='100%'>"
            message += "<tr>"
            message += "<td align='left' style='font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;word-break:break-word;'>"
            message += "<div style='font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:13px;line-height:1;text-align:left;color:#55575d;'>"
            message += "<p style='line-height: 16px; text-align: center; margin: 10px 0;font-size:12px;color:#ffffff;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;'>&copy; "+getYear+" John<span style='color:#ccc;'> Smith</span></p>"
            message += "</div>"
            message += "</td>"
            message += "</tr>"
            message += "</table>"
            message += "</div>"
            message += "<!--[if mso | IE]>"
            message += "</td>"
            message += "</tr>"
            message += "</table>"
            message += "<![endif]-->"
            message += "</td>"
            message += "</tr>"
            message += "</tbody>"
            message += "</table>"
            message += "</div>"
            message += "<!--[if mso | IE]>"
            message += "</td>"
            message += "</tr>"
            message += "</table>"
            message += "<![endif]-->"
            message += "</div>"
            message += "</body>"
            message += "</html>"
        return message;
    }
}

module.exports = contactMail;
```

**Screenshot of email result I receive:**

[image]

Comment: Is that an email client you're viewing it in? Unfortunately, this could be something your email client is doing automatically.

Comment: Yes those results are being viewed in gmail. The same is occurring across some other email clients as well. The only ones where it doesn't show up like that are yahoo and majority others. Does that mean this is out of my control on customizing it to change color for those specific email clients?

Comment: Yes, someone else could chime in but I'm afraid it is automatic. You may find a way to change it, but I don't personally know of one.

Comment: Okay thanks. I'll keep trying some ideas if I can't figure it out I'll just have to accept it i guess.